# com.playtika.testcontainers vs org.testcontainers

Tags: containers, testcontainers

I'm have a bit of confusion as I am trying to mock up some container dbs and looking around at whats available many refer to both of these libs such as this example:

https://github.com/mydeveloperplanet/myliquibaseplanet/blob/feature/testcontainers/pom.xml

however I am running into many issues between managing them locally and integrating them into my bitbucket pipeline.

Is there some solid documentation in regards just spinning up a db container and which versions of these two libs are compatible with each other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://github.com/Playtika/testcontainers-spring-boot is a wrapper around https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java that provides auto configurations for Spring Boot and pre-configures containers.

The main library is testcontainers-java and you should refer to its documentation:
https://www.testcontainers.org

Also, the Spring Boot team made some great progress towards easier integration and today it is very easy to use testcontainers-java with Spring Boot:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-testcontainers